# Printed double value differs from originally set value

Tags: swift

I am adding two array which contains double values

```
 let arrayA = [1.1,2.3]
 let arrayB = [4.2,5.5,6.8]

 let c = arrayA + arrayB

 print("\(c)");
```

The print function is printing following result :

```
[1.1000000000000001, 2.2999999999999998, 4.2000000000000002, 5.5, 6.7999999999999998]
```

How to get exact double values after adding arrays ?

Comment: its called precision value you can control using %.2f ..

Comment: Compare also [Why are doubles printed differently in dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959254/why-are-doubles-printed-differently-in-dictionaries) – this is the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. It's the way `Double` (and `Float`) does work.

As workaround you can round your values when you are going to print them

```
for num in c {
    print(String(format: "%.1f", num))
}
```

> 1.1
>
> 2.3
>
> 4.2
>
> 5.5
>
> 6.8

Answer (score 1):

You need to change as below :

defind type of array because you have not defined at now .

```
 let arrayA : [CGFloat] = [1.1,2.3]
 let arrayB : [CGFloat] = [4.2,5.5,6.8]
```

Comment: @shallowThought did you check output ?

Comment: @shallowThought i have check output after that i have posted my answer .

Comment: You are right. I understood the question as "why does 1.1(0000000) become 1.00000001. You are fixing the printed format. Can notre -upvote as "the vote is locked until the answer is updated". Sorry. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for what you are seeing (`1.1` -> `1.1000000000000001`) lies in the nature of floating points. It is caused by rounding errors, as the infinite nature of real numbers can not be presented in its finite memory (floating point) representation.

This might not be a big issue in your case, as you can change the printed format as stated in other answers, but can cause hard to track bugs, especially when comparing floating point numbers. For instance, the following code:

```
let result = 1.1 * 3.0

if result == 3.3 {
    print("I thought so!")
} else {
    print("This might be unexpected")
}
```

prints:

```
This might be unexpected
```

For more information I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html):