# Why are doubles printed differently in dictionaries?

Tags: swift

```
let dic : [Double : Double] = [1.1 : 2.3, 2.3 : 1.1, 1.2 : 2.3]

print(dic)// [2.2999999999999998: 1.1000000000000001, 1.2: 2.2999999999999998, 1.1000000000000001: 2.2999999999999998]



let double : Double = 2.3
let anotherdouble : Double = 1.1

print(double) // 2.3
print(anotherdouble) // 1.1
```

I don't get that why is the compiler printing values from dictionaries differently?
I'm on Swift 3, Xcode 8. Is this a bug or some weird way of optimizing stuff or something?

### EDIT

What's even more weird is that :

Some values go over, some go below, some stay as they are! 1.1 is less than 1.1000000000000001 while 2.3 is more than 2.2999999999999998, 1.2 is just 1.2

Comment: Doesn't look like a bug exactly, but it is a bit inconsistent

Comment: FWIW, the exact values of 1.1 and 2.3 are 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 and 2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875, explaining the direction and magnitude of the deviation

Comment: @harold what do you mean their exact value is that. I'm not following. Where/how did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: This is the nature of floating point numbers. Find more details [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40526353/1457385).

Comment: And 1.2 is 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, which rounds up to 1.2 if printed with a precision that includes all those 9's but not the first 5

Comment: @shallowThought I'm reading into it, interesting but that doesn't explain why a normal print of the number is printed different from it being printing within a dictionary or does it?

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't use a dictionary with doubles as keys anyway.

Comment: @harold As keys, not at values.hmmm something to keep in mind thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, a `Double` cannot store
the value `1.1` exactly. Swift uses (like many other languages)
binary floating point numbers according to the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
standard.

The closest number to `1.1` that can be represented as a `Double` is

```
1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
```

and the closest number to `2.3` that can be represented as a `Double` is

```
2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

*Printing* that number means that it is converted to a string with
a decimal representation again, and that is done with different
precision, depending on how you print the number.

From the source code at [HashedCollections.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2149) one can see that the `description` method of
`Dictionary` uses `debugPrint()` for both keys and values, 
and `debugPrint(x)` prints the value of `x.debugDescription`
(if `x` conforms to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`).

On the other hand, `print(x)` calls `x.description` if `x` conforms
to `CustomStringConvertible`.

So what you see is the different output of `description`
and `debugDescription` of `Double`:

```
print(1.1.description) // 1.1
print(1.1.debugDescription) // 1.1000000000000001
```

From the Swift source code one can see
that both use the `swift_floatingPointToString()`
function in [Stubs.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/stubs/Stubs.cpp#L185), with the `Debug` parameter set to `false` and `true`, respectively.
This parameter controls the precision of the number to string conversion:

```
int Precision = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10;
if (Debug) {
  Precision = std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10;
}
```

For the meaning of those constants, see [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

- `digits10` – number of decimal digits that can be represented without change,
- `max_digits10` – number of decimal digits necessary to differentiate all values of this type.

So `description` creates a string with less decimal digits. That
string can be converted to a `Double` and back to a string giving
the same result.
`debugDescription` creates a string with more decimal digits, so that
any two different floating point values will produce a different output.

Comment: Interesting. So I just tried `let dic : [Double : Double] = [1.1 : 2.3, 1.1000000000000001 : 2.3]` and I got error **fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys** ... while unsurprisingly `let dic : [Double : Double] = [1.1 : 2.3, 1.10000000000000031 : 2.3]` doesn't create an error. Also not sure if I would fully understand this in one bite. Time will help:)

Comment: @Honey: Yes, both values are converted to the same 64-bit binary floating point number when stored in a Double. Try `let x = 1.1; let y = 1.1000000000000001; print(x == y)`.

Comment: so you mean every double always has a representation in a 16 decimal precision format?

Comment: @Honey: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. `Float` and `Double` use the IEEE 754 standard, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. This thread is very instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.

Comment: I mean there are 16 digits after `.` ie they are represented in such a format

Comment: @Honey there are not, though that's a common choice for printing. They're not stored in decimal in the first place, see the linked articles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Swift uses binary floating numbers while storing it into dictionary

Use dictionary as [Double: Any], use Float if your number is 32 bit then upcast to AnyObject

See below example

```
    let strDecimalNumber  = "8.37"    
    var myDictionary : [String: Any] = [:] 
    myDictionary["key1"] = Float(strDecimalNumber) as AnyObject  // 8.369999999999999
    myDictionary["key2"] = Double(strDecimalNumber) as AnyObject  //8.369999999999999
    myDictionary["key3"] = Double(8.37) as AnyObject   //8.369999999999999
    myDictionary["key4"] = Float(8.37) as AnyObject  //8.37
    myDictionary["key5"] = 8.37  // 8.3699999999999992
    myDictionary["key6"] = strDecimalNumber  // "8.37" it is String
    myDictionary["key7"] = strDecimalNumber.description  // "8.37" it is String
    myDictionary["key8"] = Float(10000000.01)  // 10000000.0
    myDictionary["key9"] = Float(100000000.01) // 100000000.0
    myDictionary["key10"] = Float(1000000000.01) // 1e+09 
    myDictionary["key11"] = Double(1000000000.01) // 1000000000.01
    print(myDictionary)
```

myDictionary will be printed as

> ["key1": 8.37 , "key2": 8.369999999999999, "key3": 8.369999999999999,
>   "key4": 8.37, "key5": 8.3699999999999992, "key6": "8.37", "key7": "8.37" , "key8":
>   10000000.0, "key9": 100000000.0, "key10": 1e+09 ,"key11": 1000000000.01]

As mentioned by Martin R in above answer using .description will be treated as String not actual Float