# Swift tuple(Double,Double) prints strange result

Tags: swift, swift3

I print two tuples in the Xcode playground. But I get a strange result, see the following code snippet and the print result:

**Code Snippet:**

```
let x : (Double,Double) = (1.2,1.3)
print(x)

let y : (Double,Double) = (1.2,3.1)
print(y)
```

**Print Result:**

```
(1.2, 1.3)
(1.2, 3.1000000000000001)
```

Why it prints the `3.1000000000000001` which is **NOT** the actual value (3.1) I set for the tuple?

In the meantime, the `1.3` is printed out correctly.

**My Swift compiler version info:**

```
Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Comment: The linked answer is about math, but the floating point accuracy issue is basically the same.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959254/why-are-doubles-printed-differently-in-dictionaries, which explains why `print(y)` and `print(y.1)` show the number 3.1 with different precision.