# Losing precision when passing numbers through the JSONDecoder in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift4

I'm sending some JSON data to our server and in the process having issues when encoding certain values with the new Swift 4 JSONDecoder. Take this playground example:

```
import Foundation

struct QuantyTest: Codable {
    var name: String
    var value: Float
}

let json = """
[
    {
        "name": "Length",
        "value": 9.87
    },
    {
        "name": "Width",
        "value": 9.95
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
var size = try decoder.decode([QuantyTest].self, from: json)
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
var encodSize = try? encoder.encode(size)
print(String(data: encodSize!, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

So I first decode the JSON and print out the result (size). The output for  looks like this:

```
[{name "Length", value 9.87}, {name "Width", value 9.95}]
```

All good, but when I encode (size) back to JSON using the Swift JSONEncoder I get the following output:

```
[{"name":"Length","value":9.869999885559082},{"name":"Width","value":9.9499998092651367}]
```

I've tried changing value to be decimal or double but I have similar problems, the decimal output look like this:

```
[{"name":"Length","value":9.869999999999997952},{"name":"Width","value":9.95}]
```

and as a double:

```
[{"name":"Length","value":9.8699999999999992},{"name":"Width","value":9.9499999999999993}]
```

I understand that a float ,double or decimal isn't super precise but what I don't understand is why the output window shows the correct values when using float until I pass through the JSONEncoder. Im not really sure how to get around this one, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are doubles printed differently in dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959254/why-are-doubles-printed-differently-in-dictionaries) – printing a *dictionary* calls `debugDescription` on its floating point entries, and that prints the values with a higher precision.

Comment: Please use Decimal instead of Float. But Codable in Swift 4 still is incorrect in some cases. Hope Apple fix it soon. You can check the issue here:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5278?focusedCommentId=28264&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-28264

Comment: Damn floating points!!!

Comment: Looks like this issue still exists!

Comment: Still exists as of March 2020!

Comment: It does. I'm having a damn problem with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997953/2303865

Comment: Still exists as November 2020!