# How to encode Double in the long format

Tags: swift

I create a `Double` from a string using:

```
let doubleValue = Double(value)
```

The `value` is `23450000000000000000`

And in the debugger I see `doubleValue` shown as `2.345e+20`

And my code has a  encoder(to encoder:Encoder) to encode the doubleValue.

```
try container.encode(doubleValue, forKey: .akey)
```

When i run it, I see `doubleValue` is being encode as `2.345e+20`.
Is there a way to encode the `doubleValue` in the long format? i.e.  `23450000000000000000`?

Comment: What difference does it make? (possible XY problem)

Comment: Note that `Double` it is not meant to be used with such large numbers. You will loose precision. For such large  numbers not even unsigned numbers like `UInt64` would suffice. You would need to use `Decimal` type and make sure to use the string initializer.

Comment: Also when encoding/decoding Decimal types you would need to create your own encoding and decoding methods to preserve its value https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997953/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the number you'd like to print out like a `long` is too big for even a `UInt64` (where the max is `print(UInt64.max) // 2^64 = 18446744073709551615`).

If you really want to print out large values, try using a `Decimal` type.  Here's some code that worked for me:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

let doubleValue = Double(23450000000000000000)
Swift.print("hello")
Swift.print(doubleValue)

Swift.print(String(format: "%.0f", doubleValue))
var decimalValue = NSNumber(value: doubleValue).decimalValue
var result = Decimal()
NSDecimalRound(&result, &decimalValue, 0, .plain)
Swift.print(result)
```

which I dug up by looking at [Yervand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302647/981049) [to this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)

If you try even larger numbers, like "`234500000000000000000000`" (a few extra zeros in there), then you'll see the value of doing that `NSDecimalRound`.

If you simply want to print out your doubleValue in lldb, try doing `po String(format: "%.0f", doubleValue)` at a breakpoint where `doubleValue` is defined and you should have decent luck.

Comment: I wonder how this answers the question "How to encode Double in the long format". If you change the value to `Double(23450000000000000789)` it will print "23450000000000000000" as well

Comment: The way I read the question was that he wanted to print out the value (whether via a `print` or via `po` in lldb), not that he wanted to encode it ala Codable.  I guess you're trying to demonstrate the broken precision of big numbers?

Comment: OP said "Is there a way to encode the doubleValue in the long format? i.e.  23450000000000000000?" The answer would be to yes but he would need to use decimal and encode its bytes or encode it as a string. Using `Decimal` wouldn't be enough to solve the encoding issue. related https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997953/2303865