# Encode string values into Double - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Django backend that sends python `decimal` values as string (precision). I'm trying to encode `decimal` data into `Double` in my Swift app.

Here is my struct:

```
public struct MyStruct: Encodable, Decodable {
    
    public var amount: Double?

    public init(amount: Double? = nil) {
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

Possible JSONs:

```
{
    "amount" = null
}
```

or:

```
{
    "amount" = "3187.498149184"
}
```

When I try to encode my struct I get this error:

> Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.

What is the the most easiest way to do this? I have a lot of struct models containing Double values so I'm looking for a simple solution.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `Double` on the Swift end? Presumably, the Django backend isn't encoding its numbers as strings just because they felt like it; they probably wanted to benefit from the decimal-precision that comes from spelling out characters in decimal notation. That might be intentional. You might want to use a datatype that preserves this precision that they were trying to protect.

Comment: please post possible json in post. so we can get better idea

Comment: @SPatel, added JSON.

Comment: @PaulBénéteau If you would like to preserve the fraction digits of your amount you should use Swift Decimal type. Make sure also to always use its string initializer.

Comment: You can use the string encoding approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997953/2303865). It would result in `MyStruct(amount: nil)`and 
`MyStruct(amount: Optional(3187.498149184))`. Just make sure to use Decimal instead of Double in your custom structure

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your precise values into a custom `struct` with custom decoding:

```
public struct PreciseNumber: Codable {
   public let value: Decimal

   private static let posixLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
       let rawValue = try container.decode(String.self)

       value = NSDecimalNumber(string: rawValue, locale: Self.posixLocale) as Decimal
   }

   public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
       var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
       try container.encode((value as NSDecimalNumber).description(withLocale: Self.posixLocale))
   }
}
```

Then you directly decode `PreciseNumber`:

```
public var amount: PreciseNumber?
```

I have intentionally used `Decimal` instead of `Double` because a `Double` would lose precision.

A slightly more complex solution is to use a property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct NumberAsString: Codable {
    public var wrappedValue: Decimal?

    private static let posixLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let rawValue = try container.decode(String.self)
    
        guard !container.decodeNil() else {
            wrappedValue = nil
            return
        }

        wrappedValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: rawValue, locale: Self.posixLocale) as Decimal
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        guard let wrappedValue = wrappedValue else {
            try container.encodeNil()
            return
        }

        try container.encode((wrappedValue as NSDecimalNumber).description(withLocale: Self.posixLocale))
    }

    public init(wrappedValue: Decimal?) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

used as:

```
public struct MyStruct: Codable {
    @NumberAsString public var amount: Decimal?

    public init(amount: Decimal? = nil) {
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'Decimal' to expected argument type 'String?'

Comment: Maybe it is: value = NSDecimalNumber(string: rawValue).decimalValue

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: I would prefer using Double tho

Comment: @PaulBénéteau You can change the implementation to `Double` easily. Parse/encode the values using `NumberFormatter`. However, I do not see the point to use `String` to keep precision and then lose it when parsing/encoding.

Comment: Ok. What is Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") used for?

Comment: @PaulBénéteau `NSDecimalNumber` can parse values with different locales (e.g. decimal comma instead of decimal point). Using the English-US POSIX locale forces it to use the standard data format. You should use the same locale with `NumberFormatter` when parsing numbers in the standard format.

Comment: Ok I just tried your code with property wrapper but I get this error: Expected String but found null value instead.
Which is normal because some values in my json are null, how can your code handle null values?

Comment: @PaulBénéteau give me a moment, I will update it.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @PaulBénéteau Actually, that's actually caused by values that are not present at all, not `null`. Unfortunately, it seems this is now unresolvable using property wrappers since the property value is considered as a non-optional with wrapped optional value and the parsing fails already in `MyStruct` when searching for the key `amount`. I strongly recommend to use the first solution, with a normal wrapping type.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your property type to string and add custom getter to get it in Double.

```
public struct MyStruct: Encodable, Decodable {
    
    private var amount: String?

    public var getAmount: Double? {
        if let amount = amount {
            return Double(amount)
        }
        return nil
    }

    public init(amount: String? = nil) {
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

OR

```
public struct Amount: Codable {
    public let value: String?
    
    public var toDouble: Double? {
        if let val = value { return Double(val)}
        return nil
    }
    
    public init(amount: Double? = nil) {
        if let val = amount {
            self.value = String(val)
        } else {
            self.value = nil
        }
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        value = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(value)
    }
}

public struct MyStruct: Encodable, Decodable {
    
    public var amount: Amount?

    public init(amount: Double? = nil) {
        self.amount = Amount(amount: amount)
    }
}

let JSONString = """
        {
            "amount": "3187.498149184",
        }
"""


do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: Data(JSONString.utf8))
    print(result.amount?.value)
}
catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but is very complicated to implement because I have a bunch of Double properties and structs...

Comment: manually encoding& decoding is another option