# Issue with Swift Floats inside Structs

Tags: swift, struct

I'm having an issue where swift is changing my float value when it's inside a struct.. I dont think this happened on older versions of swift, but it is happening now on 4.1. Code example below... thoughts?

```
var f = Float(4.111)

print(f) // prints 4.111

struct FloatContainer {
    var f: Float
}

let container = FloatContainer(f: f)

print(container) // prints FloatContainer(f: 4.11100006)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40959254/1187415 – floating point values *inside containers* are (by default) printed with a higher precision.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common rounding error, since binary can't represent some decimal numbers. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

[Here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) is an online converter from a decimal to a floating-point representation. As you can see there is an error (`6.103515625E-8`) due to the conversion:

[image: Floating Point Converter]

As to the difference between when you print a float directly, or when you print an object that has a property that is a float, it comes down to the `description` property of objects that implement the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol. When the `print` function wants to print to the console, it invokes [_print_unlocked](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/832307c30a600c7503d296139c58931c64f9c064/stdlib/public/core/OutputStream.swift), which is an internal function that has this block:

```
if case let printableObject as CustomStringConvertible = value {
    printableObject.description.write(to: &target)
    return
}
```

So you could change your code to this in order to have the expected output:

```
struct FloatContainer : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        get {
            return f.description
        }
    }
    var f: Float
}
```

Comment: That does not yet explain why the *same value* `f` is printed as 4.111 in one place, and as 4.11100006 in another place.

Answer (score 0):

You should try printing the value inside

```
print(container.f) // prints 4.111
```

This is returning what you are storing.

Comment: Still doesn’t explain why the value is different when referencing the struct vs the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Swift provides default debug representation for any type and this is the reason [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customdebugstringconvertible)

```
 var f = Float(4.111)

    print(f) // prints 4.111

    print(f.debugDescription) // prints 4.11100006
    print(String(reflecting: f)) // default presentation according to documentation: prints 4.11100006

    struct FloatContainer: CustomStringConvertible {
        var f: Float

        // You can achieve similar output to `print(f)` with conforming
        // to `CustomStringConvertible` and implementing custom 
        // `description` implementation
        var description: String {
            return f.description
        }
    }

    let container = FloatContainer(f: f)
    // After our custom implementation the result of `print` 
    // method is the same to print(f)
    print(container) // prints FloatContainer(f: 4.111)
```