# Strange output for same Double value

Tags: ios, swift, double, precision

I have the structure as follows:

```
struct Foo {
    var number: Double

    public init(number: Double) {
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

but when i run this code ->

```
var x: Double = 1.12
let foo = Foo(number: x)

print(foo)
print(foo.number)
```

I get following output:

```
Foo(number: 1.1200000000000001)
1.12
```

I think this because of double precision but don't know how to handle it. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Btw it shows properly for me on my Xcode Playgrounds. o.O

Comment: Essentially the same reason as in [Why are doubles printed differently in dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959254/why-are-doubles-printed-differently-in-dictionaries).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in answer explained by @MartinR, [Why are doubles printed differently in dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959254/why-are-doubles-printed-differently-in-dictionaries)

It is clear that **1.1200000000000001**, is the double precision value of **1.12**.

While you are trying to print foo object, `print(foo)` object is getting printed along with its enclosed information in which `number` holds the double precisied value of **1.21**

Whereas, when you directly `print(foo.number)`, then string representation of `foo.number` is getting printed which is actually **1.21**