# JSON Conversion value from string to float

Tags: json, swift

I have a Json (received as text) that I convert it like this:

```
if let jsonData = raw.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) {
      let products = json["products"] as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
```

Products contains an array of products (also json), where I have keys which value can be String, Float, Double... one key has a value that it can be any kind of number.

This field when it is received on text from endpoint looks like this: `\"min_size\":\"0.01\"` but also can have values like `\"min_size\":\"1\"`, or `\"min_size\":\"0.001\"`. After my json conversion looks like this (printing using `po`):

```
▿ 1 : 2 elements
  - key : "min_size"
  - value : 1
```

Or

```
▿ 15 : 2 elements
  - key : "min_size"
  - value : 0.01
```

But then, when I'm trying to access it on my code (I want to read it as a float, independently if it is a 1 or a 0.01), I get this:

```
let k = item["min_size"] // contains > ▿ Optional<Any> - some : 0.01
let i = item["min_size"] as? Float // contains > nil
let j = item["min_size"] as? Int // contains > nil

let y = item["min_size"] as? NSString // contains > "0.01"
let z = y!.floatValue // contains > "0.009999997"
```

I'm new on Swift, and I don't understand what's going on here.

- Why I cannot cast directly the value (1 or 0.01) to float?
- If not, what can I do to get a float number for this field?
- And the most
  weird for me... why having a NSString that it is "0.01" converting
  value with floatValue, result is different? Rounding is not an
  option, because it could be such a long decimal too. It can be any decimal or integer number there.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't _cast_ from String to some numeric type, you need to _convert_ to a numeric type, something like `let i = Float(item["min_size"] ?? "")`

Comment: It has double quotes around it, so it's a `String`. You can't cast it as such, you need to read how to go from `String` to `Float`. For the rest it's about precision issue, like there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959254/why-are-doubles-printed-differently-in-dictionaries

Comment: swift can't allow one variable to assign 2 data type. so you need to use CGFloat in both side and assume value as 1.0 & 0.01.

Comment: My example should contain a `as? String` before the `??`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on suggestions that are on comments, solution that I implemented is:

```
let min_size = (item["min_size"] as? String ?? "").convertFromJSONStringToFloat()
```

where I have two extensions for String and Float

```
extension String {
    func convertFromJSONStringToFloat() -> Float? {
        let partNumber = self.split(separator: ".")
        return (Float(self)?.roundToDecimal((partNumber.count > 1) ? partNumber[1].count : 1))!
    }
}

extension Float {
    func roundToDecimal(_ fractionDigits: Int) -> Float {
        let multiplier = pow(10, Double(fractionDigits))
        return Float((Double(self) * multiplier) / multiplier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary has a value type of `AnyObject` and your JSON `min_size` value is a `String`, you could convert `String` into a `Float` and if it does not exist provide a default value:

```
let y = Float(item["min_size"] as? String ?? "0") ?? 0
```