# Swift Decimal Initializes with rounding error

Tags: swift3

If I do the following in Swift 3:

```
print(Decimal(0.23))
```

I get "0.2300000000000000512".

Is there a better way to initialize it other than:

```
print(Decimal(string:"0.23"))
```

Comment: You can do `Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -2, significand: 23)`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40526353/1457385